# How to convert a field to spaces blindly

Tags: datastage

I have a delimited sequential file.  This file has a field that is variable length.  I want to make this field blank.  Can some suggest how to convert the field to spaces?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are not providing much information - so my advise is: Load it - replace the field - write it. If you want better answers you have to provide more details.

Comment: Thanks much.  This is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is this expression in a Transformer stage

```
Space(Len(InLink.MyString))
```

Comment: Thanks much.  I paired the Space function with the Index function and Substring to get the desired result.